# Роутинг в табах

Tags: angularjs

Не работает роутинг, больше всего интересует роутинг в табах, очень мало примеров и нет четких инструкций
[Пример кода](http://embed.plnkr.co/NC0MQfgrzXmHcvsHWLWE/)

index.html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="ha-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">

          <li class="current"><a ui-sref="homepage" >Обо Мне</a></li>
          <li><a  ui-sref="myportfolio" >Мое портфолио</a></li>
          <li><a ui-sref="services" >Услуги</a></li>
          <li><a ui-sref="contacts" >Мои контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div ui-view>

</div>
```

services.html

```
<div ng-controller="tabsController">
    <uib-tabset>
        <uib-tab ng-repeat = "tab in tabs" heading = "{{tab.title}}" active = "tab.active" disable = "tab.disabled">
            <div ui-view = "{{tab.route}}"></div>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('Plunker', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
        .state('homepage', {
            url: "/homepage",
            templateUrl: "homepage/homepage.html"
        })
        .state('myportfolio', {
                url: "/myportfolio",
                templateUrl: "myportfolio/my-portfolio.html"
            })
        .state('services', {
            url: "",
            views: {
              "tab1": { templateUrl: "tab1.html" },
              "tab2": { templateUrl: "tab2.html" },
              "tab3": { templateUrl: "tab3.html" },
            }
          })
          .state('contacts', {
            url: "/contacts",
            templateUrl: "contacts/contacts.html"
        })

    }]);

app.controller('tabsController', function($rootScope, $scope, $state){
    $scope.tabs = [
        {title: "Разработка и доработка сайтов", route: "tab1",  active: true},
        {title: "Редизайн и реверстка CMS", route: "tab2", active: false},
        {title: "Участие в разработке SPA", route: "tab3", active: false}
    ]

});
```

Comment: здесь рабочий наглядный пример что работает нет так http://radikportfolio.ru/#/services

Comment: добавьте еще html как вы их используете

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Ссылки на ваш сайт не достаточно, так как нет доступа к исходникам. Создайте пример на plunkr, в котором бы воспроизвелась ваша проблема

Comment: На вскидку проблема не в табах, а в неправильном использовании ui-route.

Comment: а в чем проблема-то кстати? на сайте табы перещелкиваются

Comment: не могу в планкер войти. Проблема в том что когда перезагружаешь страницу содержимое табов пустое, как только переходишь на другую страницу и обратно они отображаются.

Comment: в любом случае нужен рабочий пример с разметкой и скриптами

Comment: добавьте в вопрос разметку html

Comment: могу несколько исходных страниц расшарить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33927/discussion-between-radik-zu-and-grundy).

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код который у вас не работает

Comment: во-первых. вы зря удалили прошлый, такой же, вопрос. Во-вторых, ошибка проста - не используйте сразу и `ng-route`, и `ui-router`  выберите что-нибудь одно

Comment: кроме того, неизвестно что вы понимаете под _роутинг в табах_?

Comment: удалил потому что никто не помогал с вопросом. Пришлось переписывать код и убирать лишнее. именно сейчас я использую только ui-router

Comment: _никто не помогал с вопросом._ - а вы рассчитывали, что в течение 10 минут все за вас сделают? :)

Comment: такой же роут только в табах, когда я переключаю табы вместе с ними меняется содержимое табов.

Comment: пару дней прошло, за меня меня ничего не прошу сделать, прошу помощи у профессионалов

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34070/discussion-between-grundy-and-radik-zu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае проблема со state `services`.

1. Не устанавливается шаблон для самого view этого стейта, тот в котором расположены табы. Для его установки в объекте views нужно добавить поле соответствующее ui-view без имени

   ```
   views: {
     "" : "services.html", // содержимое вставится в ui-view
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Так как на странице может быть множество ui-view, на разных уровнях и для разных state, то в настройках можно указать *в какой именно* из них нужно подгрузить шаблон.
   Данный код работал был, если бы именованные ui-view: ui-view="tab1" и т.д. были прописаны в Index.html, но так как они находятся внутри ui-view, сейчас они просто не находят куда вставить шаблоны.
   Для решения необходимо указать куда именно нужно вставить. например так

   ```
   views: {
     '': { templateUrl: "services.html" },
     "tab1@services": { templateUrl: "tab1.html" },
     "tab2@services": { templateUrl: "tab2.html" },
     "tab3@services": { templateUrl: "tab3.html" },
   }
   ```

**[Исправленный Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vPVE0pd42t9sPuaNomY6?p=preview)**

Ссылке по теме:
[Nested States and Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)
[Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)