# Angular JS - ui-route и ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

В зависимости от активного элемента главного меню должно меняться содержимое сайдбра.

Содержимое index.html:

```
<body class="aside" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <div class="header-box" ng-if="skin">
  <header class="header">
   <div class="wrapper" ui-view="header"></div>
  </header>
  <div scroll-status-bar class="statusbar"><div class="bar"></div></div>
 </div>
 <aside  class="sidebar" ui-view="aside"></aside>
 <div class="content-box">
  <div class="wrapper" ui-view="main"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Содержимое aside.html (Вот элементы li.level-1 должны отображаться и скрываться в зависимости от url):

```
<nav>
<ul class="menu-v">
    <li class="level-1 "><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/iconsGlyph">Icons</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/iconsGlyph#icons">Icons</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/iconsGlyph#glyphicons">Glyphicons</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1 "><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/nav">Navigation</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/nav#inlineDropdown">Inline dropdown</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/nav#toolsmenu">Меню инструментов</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/nav#horizontalmenu">Горизонтальное меню</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/nav#verticalmenu">Вертикальное меню</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1 "><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols"><strong>KENDO CONTROLS</strong></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols#textinputs">Text inputs</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols#selects">Selects</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols#datetimepickers">Date and time picker</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols#panelbar">Panel bar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="true" class="level-1 "><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocharts"><strong>KENDO CHARTS</strong></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocharts#areacharts">Area charts</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocharts#barcharts">Bar Charts</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocharts#boxplotcharts">Box Plot Charts</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Содержимое header.html (главное меню):

```
<nav>
<ul class="menu-h">
    <li class="level-1 dropdown">
        <a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui"><span class="link">UIKIT</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="level-2"><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/reset">Base style</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/iconsGlyph">Icons</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/controls">Controls</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1 dropdown">
        <span><span class="alt">Kendo UI</span></span>
        <ul>
            <li class="level-2"><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols">Controls</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocharts">Charts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1 dropdown">
        <span><span class="alt">SSO</span></span>
        <ul>
            <li class="level-2"><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/login"          >Форма авторизации</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/browsers/old"   >Ваш браузер устарел</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/browsers/ie"    >Необходим Internet Explorer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1 dropdown">
        <span><span class="alt">Продукты</span></span>
        <ul>
            <li class="level-2"><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/product/informator">Информатор</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('qcp', [
'ui.router',
'qcp.filters',
'qcp.services',
'qcp.directives',
'qcp.controllers',
'hljs'
])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/base/ui");

    $stateProvider
        .state('ui', {
            url: '/:currentTheme',
            abstract: true,
            views:{
                /*'toolbar' : {templateUrl:'partials/layouts/toolbar.html'},*/
                'aside'   : {templateUrl:'partials/layouts/aside.html'},
                'header'  : {templateUrl:'partials/layouts/header.html'},
                'main'    : {template   :'<div ui-view></div>'}
            },
            controller: ['$scope', '$log', 'theme', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $log, theme, $state) {
                $scope.$state = $state;
            }],
            resolve: {
                theme: ['InjectCss', '$stateParams', '$rootScope',
                    function (InjectCss, $stateParams, $rootScope) {
                        return $rootScope.changeTheme($stateParams.currentTheme)
                    }]
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit'             , {url: '/ui'                , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit-all'         , {url: '/ui/all'            , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/all.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit-reset'       , {url: '/ui/reset'          , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/reset.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.iconsGlyph'        , {url: '/ui/iconsGlyph'     , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/iconsGlyph.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.controls'          , {url: '/ui/controls'       , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/controls.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit-nav'         , {url: '/ui/nav'            , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/nav.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit-list'        , {url: '/ui/lists'          , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/lists.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit-layout'      , {url: '/ui/layouts'        , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/layouts.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit-notices'     , {url: '/ui/notices'        , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/notices.html'});

    $stateProvider.state('ui.kendo'             , {url: '/ui/kendocontrols'  , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/kendo.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.kendoCharts'       , {url: '/ui/kendocharts'    , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/kendoCharts.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.widgets'           , {url: '/widgets'           , templateUrl: 'partials/widgets.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.services'          , {url: '/services'          , templateUrl: 'partials/services.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.browsers-old'      , {url: '/browsers/old'      , templateUrl: 'partials/browsers.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.browsers-ie'       , {url: '/browsers/ie'       , templateUrl: 'partials/ie.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.error-undefined'   , {url: '/error/undefined'   , templateUrl: 'partials/error.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.error-404'         , {url: '/error/404'         , templateUrl: 'partials/404.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.error-500'         , {url: '/error/500'         , templateUrl: 'partials/500.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.login'             , {url: '/login'             , templateUrl: 'partials/login.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.informator'        , {url: '/product/informator', templateUrl: 'partials/informator/index.html'});

});
```

Например для:

```
$stateProvider.state('ui.kendo', {url: '/ui/kendocontrols', templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/kendo.html'}); 
$stateProvider.state('ui.kendoCharts', {url: '/ui/kendocharts', templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/kendoCharts.html'});
```

Должны показываться:

```
<li class="level-1 "><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols"><strong>KENDO CONTROLS</strong></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols#textinputs">Text inputs</a></li>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols#selects">Selects</a></li>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols#datetimepickers">Date and time picker</a></li>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocontrols#panelbar">Panel bar</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li ng-if="true" class="level-1 "><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocharts"><strong>KENDO CHARTS</strong></a>
    <ul>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocharts#areacharts">Area charts</a></li>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocharts#barcharts">Bar Charts</a></li>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendocharts#boxplotcharts">Box Plot Charts</a></li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

А для:

```
$stateProvider.state('ui.uikit-nav', {url: '/ui/nav', templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/nav.html'});
```

Должны показываться:

```
<li class="level-1 "><a ng-href="#{{skin}}/ui/nav">Navigation</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/nav#inlineDropdown">Inline dropdown</a></li>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/nav#toolsmenu">Меню инструментов</a></li>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/nav#horizontalmenu">Горизонтальное меню</a></li>
        <li class="level-2"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/nav#verticalmenu">Вертикальное меню</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: можете пометить для каких адресов какие пункты должны быть?

Comment: Пример вставки шаблона в конкретный ui-view можно [тут посмотреть](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480301/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%85/481178#481178)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34240/discussion-on-question-by--angular-js-ui-route--ng-if).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вариант решения, как и планировался через ng-if.
Покажу решения для примера выше. Магия заключается в следующем:

```
ng-if="state.is('ui.kendo') || state.is('ui.charts')">
```

То есть загоняем в ng-if state - [скриншот](http://prntscr.com/9qd8vs)